# Creating a colored cube with collision in Unity using C#

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine, collider

I have a plane and a cylinder to represent a human, and I make a colored cube with a script but the colliders don't work, although they are triggered as the window shows. Here is the code:

```
    GameObject plane = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Plane);
    GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    cube.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0.5F, 0);
    cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
    cube.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().isTrigger = true;
```

How come the cylinder can pass through the cube? Note that the cylinder is made within Unity.

Comment: Well, you've set `cube.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().isTrigger = true;`. Trigger colliders don't interact physically with other colliders. Furthermore, one of the objects should probably have a non-kinematic Rigidbody attached for collisions to be registered. This also depends on how you're moving your objects - if you do something like `Translate()`, physical interactions will be ignored for a frame, resulting in possible clipping. All in all, there are some likely causes but there's not enough information on your situation to give a definite answer.